# Hibernate Envers audit for many to many with composite primary Key not working for parent classes

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have entities as below with many to many relationship.Use of @Audited is working fine when adding to child classes but not working for all the entities
facing compilation error (exceptions)

Employee  class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = EMPLOYEE)
    @Audited
    public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
        @AttributeOverrides({
                @AttributeOverride(name = "Id", column = @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 50) ),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "department", column = @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT", nullable = false, length = 10) ) })
        private DepartmentId id;

        @Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
        private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "key.emp", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval=true)
        private Set<EmpAddress> empAddMap = new HashSet<EmpAddress>();


    }
```

Composite primary key class for Employee

```
    @Component
    @Embeddable
    @Audited
    public class DepartmentId implements java.io.Serializable {

        @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 50)
        private String id;

        @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT", nullable = false, length = 10)
        private String department; 

    }
```

Address Class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ADDRESS")
    @Audited
    public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5070283391974818811L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "CITY", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
        private String city

        @Column(name = "CONTACT")
        private String contact;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "key.address", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<EmpAddress> empAddMap = new HashSet<EmpAddress>();
    }
```

Mapping Class many to many relationship with Employee and Address

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS", catalog = "LRR")
    @AssociationOverrides({
            @AssociationOverride(name = "key.emp", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT") }),
            @AssociationOverride(name = "key.address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CITY") ) })
    @Audited
    public class EmpAddress {

        @EmbeddedId
        private EmpAddId key = new EmpAddId();

        @Column(name = "STATUS_ID")
        private String statusId;

    }
```

Composite primary key class for mapping entity

```
    @Embeddable
    public class EmpAddId implements Serializable {
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Employee emp;
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Address address;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think envers supports composite Id. Here there is a similar case with a turnaround: 
[Composite table with Hibernate Envers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072985/composite-table-with-hibernate-envers)

I hope it helps you!